# Lots of SQL queries/slow rendering when using inlineformset_factory (and crispy)

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Sample project with screenshots: https://github.com/nspo/slowformsets-django-example

Project with Authors, Books and Publishers.

There is a view to update an author where you can change all the books an Author has as well as add new books. The BookForms are created with an inlineformset_factory. Books also have a foreign key reference (publisher) than can be selected in the BookForm.

Rendering:

```
{% crispy form %}
{% crispy formset formset.form.helper %}
```

Problem:

- For every BookForm, there seems to be a request for all Publishers.

I *kind of* understand that there is a request for publishers, because they can be selected in an implicit ModelChoiceField. But shouldn't I be able to speed that up with prefetch_related? I have a feeling that the instance of Author passed in lines 12 and 13 of view.py might be "copied" so that any prefetched data is forgotten?

If a direct solution is not possible b/c of ModelChoiceField limitations, it would also work in my case if the Publisher cannot be changed after adding a Book (but only displayed). Not sure how to do that though without lots of changes.

Comment: I think this might be the reason for lots of SQL queries: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22841 - although I just found out that it also seems to be slow without that many queries...

Answer (score 1):

We can't see any code which makes this kind of a guessing game. You mention prefetch_related but it does not show up in the code you are linking to. In general I would do something like this

```
queryset=Book.objects.prefetch_related('publisher').filter(author=id_author)
BookInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, form=BookForm, extra=2, can_delete=False)
bookformset = BookInlineFormSet(instance=author, prefix="main", queryset=queryset)
```

Also I'm guessing that every book has exactly one publisher. So it would not be prefetch_related but select_related.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make the sample code complete. prefetch_related() like that is executed, but the result is ignored. I think this is the case b/c the ModelChoiceField of each book offers a selection of *all* publishers that exist. But it hopefully will make more sense when I get to post a sample project.

Comment: I just added a sample project (and found another problem in my original project, so at least the problem is consistent now :) )